# Array.push not working

Tags: solidity, arrays

I am new here and I am suffering with the case below, I am trying to push data into an Array, but I can't make it work, the array continuous with zero length.

```
    contract StarNotary is ERC721 { 

    struct Star { 
        string name;
        string dec;
        string mag;
        string cent;
        string story;
    }

    using Library for Library.data;
    mapping(uint256 => Star) public tokenIdToStarInfo; 
    mapping(address => uint256[]) private _ownerToTokenId; 
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) private _starsForSale;
    mapping(bytes32 => Library.data) private _hashToTokenId;

    Star[] public stars;
    uint256[] tokensForSale;

    function createStar(string _name, string _dec, string _mag, string _cent, string _story) 
    public
    returns(uint256) 
    {
        require(!checkIfStarExist(_dec, _mag, _cent), "Star already registered!");

        Star memory newStar = Star(_name,_dec,_mag,_cent,_story);

        uint256 tokenId = stars.push(newStar) - 1;

        return tokenId;

    }
}
```

Do you know what can be happing? I look for it and find nothing.

Tks
Ricardo

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine. You'll have to show how you're testing this if you need more help. The following cleaned up code works in Remix. If I pass `"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"` to a call to `createStar`, then I can fetch element `0` of `stars` and see those values.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract StarNotary { 
    struct Star { 
        string name;
        string dec;
        string mag;
        string cent;
        string story;
    }

    Star[] public stars;

    function createStar(
        string _name,
        string _dec,
        string _mag,
        string _cent,
        string _story
    )
        public
        returns (uint256) 
    {
        Star memory newStar = Star(_name, _dec, _mag, _cent, _story);

        uint256 tokenId = stars.push(newStar) - 1;

        return tokenId;

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Smarx, I am using truffle to test, look at the lines bellow

            let tokenId = await this.contract.createStar.call('awesome star!', 'dec', 'mag', 'cent', 'story');

I always get token 0.

Comment: State can't be modified in a `call`. Use `sendTransaction` instead. But note that you won't get the return value out of a transaction. Transactions don't have return values. You can log an event if you want to communicate the new `tokenId` out to the client.